# spring boot: несколько приложений в одном репозитории

Tags: spring-boot

День добрый, подскажите, насколько адекватен такой подход?
Делаю приложение, которое содержит несколько модулей 2 из которых являются SpringBootApp, которые в итоге деплоятся в докере. Или лучше каждое приложение в своем репозитории и общие модули залить куда нибудь в нексус и подтягивать их?

Comment: Блин, похоже все скатывается к монорепозиторий vs полирепозиторий)

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ. Это как вопрос разделения классов на пакеты в приложении. Можно для конкретного случая (зная много мелких деталей и специфику вашего приложения и процесса разработки) указать плюсы и минусы каждого подхода. Мы этого не знаем, а если б и знали не смогли бы за вас сделать этот выбор.